# @Where is not working when using @OneToOne mapping

Tags: hibernate, where-clause

I'm trying to put some where ccondition on one entity by using below code

```
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USA_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Where(clause = "OBJ_TYPE = 8")
    private Object object;
```

This is producing sql somithig like below (Not included the where condition):
Hibernate:

```
select object0_.OBJ_ID as OBJ1_553_0_, object0_.OBJ_TYPE as OBJ2_553_0_, object0_.OBJ_STATUS_CD as OBJ3_553_0_ from MARTINI_STORE.OBJECT object0_ where object0_.OBJ_ID=?
```

@Where working fine with @OneToMany...But my requirement is to put condition in assosicated entity of @OneToOne.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Entity 1:
 public class ObjectAttribute{
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ATR_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Where(clause = "NAME IN ('XYZ')")
private Attribute attribute;
```

}

Entity 2:

```
public class Attribute {
    @Id
@Column(name = "ATR_ID", nullable = false)
private long atrId;
```

}

Comment: Can you post your mappings?

Comment: I have added my entity details.

Comment: First, when you use "IN" you are supposed to use a list on it, not a single value: "NAME IN ('XYZ')". And second, do you have a field named "NAME" (uppercased) in your Attribute class? The field you put on a @Where clause must be same as in your class (uppercased or lowercased)

Comment: Yes I have list of names defined in the list.
e.g NAME IN ('Substitutes','contact','xyz', 'abc)

I think where condition will consider the table column names directly right?

Comment: I have always used the field name of the class instead

Comment: I have tried with the class variables but still no luck